# How to package program that requires nodejs and javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, npm, bower

I'm trying to prepare a testing project for distribution that requires nodejs and javascript. The installation process is a bit funky, and I'm trying to improve it. Here's the process I've come up with (credit to answerer of my previous question for basic idea, although it's pretty intuitive):

```
app/
```

1) user runs "bower install myProject"

```
app/
bower_components/
  myProject/
    bower_components/
      ...
    test/
      ...
    package.json
    installScript.sh
```

2) user runs `installScript.sh` from `myProject`, which calls `npm install`

```
app/
bower_components/
  myProject/
    bower_components/
      ...
    node_modules/
    package.json
    installScript.sh
test/
  ...
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'd like to use just one package manager, but one of my dependencies is jasmine, which is only available with bower.

Comment: Do you need jasmine to test your node files?  Because it is available with npm: https://www.npmjs.org/package/jasmine-node

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I need jasmine to test normal javascript files. I haven't tested whether jasmine-node works for testing normal javascript, but even if it does, I'd rather depend on one that's either explicitly for javascript or explicitly for both (I'm worried jasmine-node will use `require()` and other functions in ways normal jasmine wouldn't be able to).

Comment: http://build-podcast.com/command-line-apps/ this is a good reference for you.

Comment: @Jesse That seems like a decent reference, but how are you suggesting it will help with this? I don't see how using commander will change my install process. I'd still need to invoke something after I install the dependencies with a package manager, whether it's a nodejs cli app or a bash script, and I'd still need two package managers since this doesn't solve my jasmine dependency problem.

Comment: did you put --save dev in your package.json so that all dependencies are saved and the user can download them? Also you can make it call npm install jasmine grunt grunt-cli or whatever string of commands once you invoke npm install. They are processed as arguments with spaces as the delimiter.

Comment: @Jesse Yes, all the npm dependencies are saved. However, as I told dylants, Jasmine doesn't seem to be available with npm. I suppose I could package everything with npm and then install jasmine with bower via an invoked script. But they'd still need to get the script to call, which would be in node_modules, so the top level command would have to be `npm install myproject node_modules/myproject/grunt`. It leaves me in the same position (needing to use two package managers and use an install script), the only difference being npm is called first and bower second instead of vice versa.

Comment: Hmmm not sure about how to fix that.